# Uncommonly common recommendation on Neo4j with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to implement a basic recommendation system on Neo4j. Basically, I have users and artists liked by users. I would like to query "users who liked damien rice, also liked these artists". That's easy with following:

```
MATCH (n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})
RETURN n.artist_name, COUNT(n) AS COUNT
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Although this approach is kind of true, it returns Coldplay, The Beatles (users which are popular for everyone) as follows:

```
n.artist_name        COUNT
coldplay             6193
radiohead            5377
the beatles          3998
death cab for cutie  3647
muse                 3252
the killers          3064
jack johnson         2966
```

I tend to figure out *uncommonly common* suggestions. My intended approach is to give a score to coldplay with calculating (6193/totalNumberOfLikesForColdplay). For example, if total of 61930 people liked coldplay, then it has a score 9163/91630 = 0.1 and I want to sort all artists depending on this score.

I tried the following:

```
MATCH (n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})
MATCH (n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)
RETURN n.artist_name, COUNT(n)/COUNT(n2) AS SCORE
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 30
```

But it tooks forever. What kind of query should I type to get the result in the most efficient way?

**Edit:** I just realized that the query I tried above is not that I want. It calculates
*numberOfPeopleBothLikedColdplay_DamienRice/numberOfPeopleLikedDamienRice*
*numberOfPeopleBothLikedTheBeatles_DamienRice/numberOfPeopleLikedDamienRice*
and so on

However I want to calculate *numberOfPeopleBothLikedColdplay_DamienRice/numberOfPeopleLikedColdplay*
*numberOfPeopleBothLikedTheBeatles_DamienRice/numberOfPeopleLikedTheBeatles*
...

So maybe it can be updated as

```
MATCH (n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})
MATCH (n2:Artist {artist_name: n.name})<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)
RETURN n.artist_name, COUNT(p)/COUNT(p2) AS SCORE
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 30
```

But now, it returns me "(no rows)" as result.

**Edit2:** As it is suggested, I updated query as follows:

```
MATCH (p2:Person)-[:LIKES]->(n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->
  (n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})
RETURN n.artist_name, COUNT(p)/COUNT(p2) AS SCORE
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 30
```

But it still runs forever. By the way, I have 292516 artists, 359347 People, 17549962 LIKES relations between artist and people. And you can assume a :Person can only like an :Artist once, and that only :Persons can like :Artists

Comment: If you would like to calculate the number of likes, you should count the "persons" that liked the artist, i.e. use `COUNT(p)/COUNT(p2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some improvements we can make here.

It's helpful to understand why your query may be taking so long. Recall that Neo4j returns what amounts to rows of columns of data, and this is built up as you progress through your query. After your second match, what is being built up are rows consisting of n2, and every combination of person who likes n2 with every person who likes n2 (since your second match creates a cartesian product on this same set of persons) with every other artist liked by these people. It's a highly inefficient query (n^2 at least in complexity), and a long or never-finishing execution time is fully expected.

So let's fix that up.

First, we can get rid of the second match entirely for calculating the number of likes for n2. Instead (assuming a :Person can only like an :Artist once, and that only :Persons can like :Artists) we can count the number of :LIKES relationships directly. By reordering this first, we also ensure that this operation only happens once for a single row of data rather than being duplicated for a great number of rows. Then we can run the first MATCH.

```
MATCH (n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})
WITH n2, SIZE( (n2)<-[:LIKES]-() ) as n2Likes
MATCH (n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-()-[:LIKES]->(n2)
WITH n, toFloat(COUNT(n))/n2Likes AS SCORE
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 30
RETURN n.artist_name, SCORE
```

EDIT to address clarified requirements. Also, altered queries to use float values for the count, so the resulting score is a decimal rather than an int.

We can use a similar approach of getting the SIZE() of the likes of each artist.

```
MATCH (n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-()-[:LIKES]->(n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})
WITH n, toFloat(COUNT(n)) as likesBothCnt
WITH n, likesBothCnt, SIZE( ()-[:LIKES]->(n) ) as likesArtist
WITH n, likesBothCnt/likesArtist as SCORE
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 30
RETURN n.artist_name, SCORE
```

However this query will definitely be slower than the first one I proposed. One way you could improve the speed is by caching a snapshot of the like count per artist on the artist node ahead of time, then using the cached value when you need a real-time calculation. You would need to figure out how and when to update the cached values, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @InverseFalcon , Your query is quite fast, however I just made a edit on the question, could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Depending on your suggestion and my edit, I updated the query as follows:

MATCH (p2:Person)-[:LIKES]->(n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->
  (n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})

RETURN n.artist_name, COUNT(p)/COUNT(p2) AS SCORE

ORDER BY SCORE DESC

LIMIT 30

But still running forever

Comment: Updated my answer per the new requirements.

Comment: Thanks, it is working right now (just replace WTIH - WITH in your code). And I got your point how to increase performance to keep extra information in the cache. 

By the way, I realized that this is not a perfect solution. For example, there are some artists which retrieved only 1 like from a person. And that person also liked damien rice as well. Their score is 1/1 = 1 and they get the top position in the result set.

Comment: Maybe I should filter these results with only displaying the artists which get at least 10% likes number of the damien rice. Or displaying the artists which get at least 10% likes number of the damien rice. Or likesBothCnt should not bi bigger than 0.3*likesArtist. I should check with how we can use IF clauses in query

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using two separate `MATCH` clauses? Using two `MATCH` clauses has different semantics than using a single one, see the notes in the Cypher documentation on [uniqueness](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypherdoc-uniqueness). In the current case, using two `MATCH` clauses allows `p2` to take the same value as `p`.

```
MATCH
  (n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->
  (n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"})<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)
RETURN n.artist_name, COUNT(p)/COUNT(p2) AS SCORE
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 30
```

You can also repeat the variable in the same `MATCH` clause and have the same set of results. For example:

```
MATCH
  (n:Artist)<-[:LIKES]-(p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(n2:Artist {artist_name: "damien rice"}),
  (n2)<-[:LIKES]-(p2:Person)
RETURN n.artist_name, COUNT(p)/COUNT(p2) AS SCORE
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , However I just made a edit on the question, could you please have a look at it?